# Java - Split String using regex and new line

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

I have a file that I scan into my program and store in a String using this code:

```
    try {
        data= new Scanner(new File("file.csv")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

The file.csv looks something like this:

```
"RowA";"RowB"
55;56
57;58
59;60
61;62
```

Now, I'm trying to extract each number and put them in a String[] like so:

```
    String[] number= data.split(";|\\r?\\n|\"|[a-zA-Z]");
```

When I print the code like so:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Line: " + number[i]);
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
Line: 
Line:  
Line:  
Line:  
Line:  
Line:  
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 
Line: 55
Line: 56
Line: 57
Line: 58
Line: 59
Line: 60
Line: 61
Line: 62
```

Why are the first indexes in the array blank and how can I remove it?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not read lines one-after-another and split the strings using ";"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this regex :

```
;|\r?\n|"|[a-zA-Z]
```

- `"` matches the double quotes in the String (`"RowA";"RowB"`)
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches each character in `"RowA";"RowB"`.

Hence it is split at all those places and you get the blanks.

You can remove these parts if you don't need them, using:

```
String[] number= data.split(";|\\r?\\n");
```

I can also see that you want only numbers in your data, and not " and characters. In that case, you can replace the `"` and characters by using `replaceAll()`, before you split it.

```
data.replaceAll("\"|[a-zA-Z]","");
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you, sir! However, I have parsed each row to it's own int[] but it is showing a 0 (zero) between each number: 55, 0, 57, 0, 59, 0 and so on.. Im guessing this has something to do with the regex and it is parsing a blank space or something to a zero. Any ideas?

Comment: I found my error. It was in my for loop and had nothing to do with your answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution to your regex see the answer by @Hackerdarshi.

However, I propose an alternative method, which is likely more efficient to parse the numbers.

Instead of reading the whole file into a String and then using Regex to parse the numbers, you can instead read the file line by line, split each line on `";"` and then parse each number returned by the split:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

File file = new File("file.csv");

try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)){
    bufferedReader.readLine();    

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        for (final String number : line.split(";")) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
        }
    }
} catch(final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: do you really think your method is *likely more efficient* than a regex? Why?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes, one moment

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you want an element for every group of consecutive digits a quick and easy solutions would be:

```
String[] number= data.split("([^0-9])+");
```

This will provide your expected output as long as every value you expect is an integer (no decimal separator) and that there is no digits anywhere else.

EDIT:
If the first/last char of *data* is not a digit it will add **one** empty item at the start/end of the *number* array.